# Is unserialize really unsafe for all systems?

Tags: php, class, security, oop, serialization

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/unserialize), it's unsafe to use unserialize with untrusted input.

As a test, I wrote:

```
<?php
global $secret;
$secret = 'SuperSecret';

class Thing {
    
    public static function __wakeup() {
        var_dump($GLOBALS);
    }
    
    public function __unserialize() {
        return 'okay';
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    echo 'serializing=';
    echo serialize(new Thing() );
}

$unser = unserialize($_GET['thing']);
```

First go to ?s, then it shows: O:5:"Thing":0:{}

Go to ?thing=O:5:"Thing":0:{} and it will show all global variables - a security risk.

But what if there is no class that has such unsafe __wakeup() function? Isn't unserialize safe for (most) systems that don't have 'unsafe' __wakeup functions?

Comment: Are you solving some particular problem with this solution (then you're doing it wrong) or just curious?

Comment: Trying to understand why this is dangerous to use in code - it looks like the solution here should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874744/limiting-unserialize-to-return-arrays

Comment: it's safe to not use it

Comment: @zerkms Nope, see the answer below.

Comment: yes, see the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article on it.

https://blog.alertlogic.com/blog/writing-exploits-for-exotic-bug-classes-unserialize()/

Basically the unserialize can be used to rewrite or change classes that are important to PHP or your script.

Comment: I thought I saw that article, or one like it before - Looks like their example is exactly the type prevented in the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874744/limiting-unserialize-to-return-arrays